# How to display Json Data in a carousel slider in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I am getting `Json` Data from an API. I want to display the data in `Carousel` slider. I tried my best to display but not find the results. I am new in `angular 2.` I know the `Interpolation {{}}` sign in used to display but I add the data for understanding Here is my `HTML` file :

```
<div class="carousel slide media-carousel" id="media2">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">

                            <div class="item active">
                                <div class="row col-md-12" style="padding: 0px;">
                                    <div class="col-md-3 text-center slider_Itm">
                                        <div style="height: 160px; width: 264px; background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), rgba(0,0,0,0.2) url('app/images/Assets/mob1.png') no-repeat center;">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slider_cntnt" style="margin-left: 0px">
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_name">Iphone</p>
                                                <p class="slider_Prod_city">RS 26,000</p>
                                                <p class="slider_Prod_price">Lahore</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 text-center slider_Itm">
                                        <div style="height: 160px; width: 264px; background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)), rgba(0,0,0,0.75) url('app/images/Assets/mob2.png') no-repeat center;color: white;font-family: 'Montserrat'; font-weight: 400; font-size: 11px;line-height: 26px;">

                                            <div style="padding-top: 30px;">Qualcomm Snapdragon 801</div>
                                            <div>2.3 GHz Quad-core CPU</div>
                                            <div>5.0" Corning Gorilla Glass</div>
                                            <div>3GB RAM/16GB ROM</div>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slider_cntnt" style="margin-left: 0px">
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_name">IPHONE 5S</p>
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_city">RS 26,000</p>
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_price">Lahore</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 text-center slider_Itm">
                                        <div style="height: 160px; width: 264px; background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), rgba(0,0,0,0.2) url('app/images/Assets/mob1.png') no-repeat center;">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slider_cntnt" style="margin-left: 0px">
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_name">IPHONE 5S</p>
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_city">RS 26,000</p>
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_price">Lahore</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 text-center slider_Itm">
                                        <div style="height: 160px; width: 264px; background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), rgba(0,0,0,0.2) url('app/images/Assets/mob1.png') no-repeat center;">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slider_cntnt" style="margin-left: 0px">
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_name">IPHONE 5S</p>
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_city">RS 26,000</p>
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_price">Lahore</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="row col-md-12" style="padding: 0px;">
                                    <div class="col-md-3 text-center slider_Itm">
                                        <div style="height: 160px; width: 264px; background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), rgba(0,0,0,0.2) url('app/images/Assets/mob1.png') no-repeat center;">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slider_cntnt" style="margin-left: 0px">
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_name">IPHONE 5S</p>
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_city">RS 26,000</p>
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_price">Lahore</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 text-center slider_Itm">
                                        <div style="height: 160px; width: 264px; background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)), rgba(0,0,0,0.75) url('app/images/Assets/mob2.png') no-repeat center;color: white;font-family: 'Montserrat'; font-weight: 400; font-size: 11px;line-height: 26px;">

                                            <div style="padding-top: 30px;">Qualcomm Snapdragon 801</div>
                                            <div>2.3 GHz Quad-core CPU</div>
                                            <div>5.0" Corning Gorilla Glass</div>
                                            <div>3GB RAM/16GB ROM</div>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slider_cntnt" style="margin-left: 0px">
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_name">IPHONE 5S</p>
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_city">RS 26,000</p>
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_price">Lahore</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 text-center slider_Itm">
                                        <div style="height: 160px; width: 264px; background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), rgba(0,0,0,0.2) url('app/images/Assets/mob1.png') no-repeat center;">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slider_cntnt" style="margin-left: 0px">
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_name">IPHONE 5S</p>
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_city">RS 26,000</p>
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_price">Lahore</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 text-center slider_Itm">
                                        <div style="height: 160px; width: 264px; background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), rgba(0,0,0,0.2) url('app/images/Assets/mob1.png') no-repeat center;">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slider_cntnt" style="margin-left: 0px">
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_name">IPHONE 5S</p>
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_city">RS 26,000</p>
                                            <p class="slider_Prod_price">Lahore</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <a data-slide="prev" href="#media2" class="left carousel-control" style="background: transparent; color: #1b99e3; opacity: 1;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" style="top: 10px; left: 11px;"></span></a>
                        <a data-slide="next" href="#media2" class="right carousel-control" style="background: transparent; color: #1b99e3; opacity: 1;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="top: 10px; left: 0px;"></span></a>
                    </div>



{
"error": "TheErrorData",
"body": "helloworld",
"data": [{
        "Brand_id": 0,
        "Brand_name": "Samsung",
        "id":0
    },
    {
        "Brand_id": 1,
        "Brand_name": "QMobile",
        "id":1
    },
    {
        "Brand_id": 2,
        "Brand_name": "Nokia",
        "id":0
    },
    {
        "Brand_id": 3,
        "Brand_name": "Huawei",
        "id":1
    },
    {
        "Brand_id": 4,
        "Brand_name": "Acer",
        "id":0
    }
]
```

}

In type Script file.

```
indexmobileshelf = [];

constructor(private _employeelist : SubServices){
}
ngOnInit()
{  
    this._employeelist.MobileShelf()         
    .subscribe(data => this.indexmobileshelf = data);  
}
```

I added files.. a servive is call from my type script file having a finction namr MobileShelf() which Return Json data in **indexmobileshelf** then i use this data to display in carousel slider. kindly help me out

Answer (score 0):

you can use the looping *ngFor for all the repeating elements

suppose you want to display items for the array.
Your code is a little messed up to read. but you can understand the concept and apply accordingly

```
<div class="col-md-3 text-center slider_Itm" *ngFor="let mobile of indexmobileshelf">
   <div style="height: 160px; width: 264px; background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), rgba(0,0,0,0.2) url('app/images/Assets/mob1.png') no-repeat center;"></div>
        <div class="slider_cntnt" style="margin-left: >
           <p class="slider_Prod_name">{{mobile.Brand_id}}
           <p class="slider_Prod_city">{{mobile.Brand_name}}</p>
           <p class="slider_Prod_price">{{mobile.somethingelse}}</p>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am also using loop, but the issue comes it shows all the data in a single Carousel. How can I show the Data in each Carousel using a loop.  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjqTd.png)